# Optimal maximum Parquet file size in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet

I'm trying to work out what the optimal file size when partitioning Parquet data on S3. AWS recommends [avoiding having files less than 128MB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/). But is there also a recommended maximum file size?

Databricks recommends [files should be around 1GB](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/101/what-is-an-optimal-size-for-file-partitions-using.html), but it's not clear to me whether this only applies to HDFS. I know that the optimal file size is dependent on the HDFS block size. However, S3 doesn't have any concept of block size.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You Should probably consider two things:

1) in case of pure object stores such as s3, it does not matter on s3 side what is your block size - you don't need to align to anything.

2) what is more important is how and with what are you going to read the data? 
Consider partitioning, pruning, rowgroups and predicate pushdowns - also how you'll going to join this?

e.g.: Presto (Athena) prefers files that are over 128Mb, but too big will cause poor parallelisation - i usually aim for 1-2gb files

Redshift prefers to be massively parallel, so e.g. 4 nodes, 160 files will be better then 4 nodes 4 files :)

suggested read: 
https://www.upsolver.com/blog/aws-athena-performance-best-practices-performance-tuning-tips
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/